# JQuery how to go up a directory

Tags: jquery, html, directory

How do I go up one directory level in my jquery code? Below is my code.  It is referencing a folder on my c drive called "uploads", except I don't see "uploads" anywhere in my html... how does it know to look there? and how can i move up a directory to the main C level, so that I can navigate into a different folder?

```
    <div><div style="height:0px;overflow:hidden"></div>  
    <div id='426489085654210420-slideshow'></div>  
    <script type='text/javascript'>  
        (function(jQuery) {
        function init() {
            wSlideshow.render({
                elementID:"426489085654210420",
                nav:"none",
                navLocation:"left",
                captionLocation:"bottom",
                transition:"fade",
                autoplay:"1",
                speed:"4",
                aspectRatio:"auto",
                showControls:"true",
                randomStart:"false",
                images:[{
                    "url":"project1.jpg","width":"400","height":"168"
                },{
                    "url":"project2.jpg","width":"400","height":"226"
                },{
                    "url":"project3.jpg","width":"400","height":"265"
                }]
            })
        }
    jQuery ? jQuery(init) : document.observe('dom:loaded', init)
    })
(window._W && _W.jQuery)
</script>
```

Comment: Where is the reference to your C drive showing up?

Comment: What is the URL of the page that contains the code? If you have relative URLs in your HTML or Javascript, they'll be interpreted relative to the directory of the URL.

Comment: The question isn't clear, but I suspect what you need is something like `url: "../images/project1.jpg"`.

Comment: I can only see the reference to the C drive by viewing the source code.  It does not show up in my actual code.

Comment: I have no idea where that's coming from.

Comment: There's no way that Javascript can affect the source code. It only modifies the DOM, which is created after loading the source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go up a level in the hierarchy by prefixing URLs with `../`

```
            images:[{
                "url":"../project1.jpg","width":"400","height":"168"
            },{
                "url":"../project2.jpg","width":"400","height":"226"
            },{
                "url":"../project3.jpg","width":"400","height":"265"
            }]
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? You can use `substr()` to return part of a string.